# Point-domain functions: $f(T), T(x,y)$

Tags: functions

I'm doing a seminar paper in Computing and main part of my idea is mapping $x$ and $y$ components of a point into new $x$ and $y$, resulting in a new point. There is more, but that's the core idea.

I figured I'd use functions that take points as input and output new points. But I can't figure out a notation I should use. I'm actually BAS Computing student, I had mathematics, but not enough to figure this out on my own. And I failed to find the answer using Google.

The only alternative I can think of is using a function with 2 parameters, but concept is more intuitively software-implementable if I use point-based functions. I need both $x$ and $y$ for evaluation because of condition matching.

So how do I define a function that takes a point and maps it to a new point, including conditions regarding $x$ and $y$ components before mapping?

DOMAIN: $T_1(x, y)$, $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$

CODOMAIN: $T_2(f(x), g(x))$

**EDIT:**

The only way I managed to think of is this one:

$T(x,y)$

$h(T) = { T1(f(x), g(y)) | condition}$

Example condition: $h(T) = { T1(f(x), g(y)) | x>0, y>0}$

Is it correct or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that function arguments are a tuple, and every point in space is representable in a tuple. So if I have...

$h(x,y)=(f(x),g(y))$

... I can just pass the 2D point without a bother and I'm sure to get a tuple, which could be assigned to a new 2D point. Please correct me if I'm wrong.